# How to check that a user's input is a string and not a number

Tags: java, string, user-input

I've been given an exercise to ask a user for their name using a method. If the user doesn't input any text they should be asked again. I've got it working but if the user inputs a number it still prints out. How can I stop the user from being able to input a number?

Here's my code below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // call method
    System.out.println("Hello " + getName());

}

public static String getName() {
    // input a scanner
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // declare vars
    String userName = "";

    // while loop
    while (userName.equals("")) {
        // ask user for input
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        userName = scanner.nextLine();

    }
    scanner.close();
    return userName;

}
```

}

Comment: Use `Integer.parseInt(String)`;

Comment: Should something like `William 2` be allowed?

Comment: You need to consider what values are considered valid and then create a method to test against these conditions. For example, is 'J0e 8loggs' a valid name? Once you know the criteria to validate against you can choose a viable solution.

Comment: Why are you so sure that names cannot consist of digits? Do you know all of the world's naming systems? If you impose restrictions on name entries, it's quite probable that in the long run they turn out to be inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use regular expression.

```
String namePattern = "[^\\p{P}|^\\d+]+";

//true if name contains only alphabets, false - otherwise
boolean result = userName.matches(namePattern);
```

Comment: Why would we use `.matches()` when `Scanner` has a method `hasNext(pattern)` that checks this.

Answer (score 0):

As regex is generally slow, a non-regex solution would be:

```
boolean containsDigit(final String string) {
    boolean result = false;

    if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
        return result;
    }

    char[] characters = string.toCharArray();
    for (char character : characters) {
        if (Character.isDigit(character)) {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

This will result in the following while-loop

```
while (userName.equals("") || containsDigit(userName)) {
    ...
}
```

Note: a cleaner alternative would be to use `username.isEmpty()` instead of `username.equals("")`

Comment: Why would we need to reinvent the weel when when `Scanner` has its own method `hasNextInt()` that checks if the next line is an `int`.

Comment: That is because `Scanner#hasNextInt()` does not check the *next line*, but the *next token*. This means it will correctly return `true` on `943320` but return incorrectly false on `John 69`.

Answer (score 0):

Well [**Scanner**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) has several methods to treat the user input. One of the methods that you can use to check if the user input is an `int` is **[`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt(int))**:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value in the specified radix using the nextInt() method.

So your code will be :

```
if(!scanner.hasNextInt()){
     userName = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

Another approach is to use [`hasNext(Pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern)) method with a pattern that matches only alphabetic strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to, you could also use a 3rd party lib like `ApacheCommons`, and use their `StringUtils.isAlpha()` method.

The `isAlpha()` method also checks to see if the string provided is `null` or empty.